# Raspberry Pi3 error message: "Bad dumping mode"

Tags: raspberry-pi3

Raspberry Pi3 Model B+ was freezed with a message

---

Oops - undefined instructions: 0 [#1] SMP ARM
Bad dumping mode, switching to all CPUs dump
Dumping ftrace buffer:
  (ftrace buffer empty)

### Modules linked in: rfcomm bnep hci_uart btbcm bluetooth endev brcmfmac brcmutil

And then the processor was stuck, nothing happened after this error message. The main task was that I was trying to install "dlib". Any ideas about the error, is Raspberry broken, problems with the memory card, operating system, system programs, kernel? How to continue?

-TTviewer

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?